# display progress doesn't work install4j

Tags: install4j

I want the change Display Progress highlighted steps when proceeding to next actions within the same screen.

I tried the following java scripts to run after each action:

```
context.goForward(1, true, true);
```

or

```
context.getWizardContext().setWizardIndexKey("2");
```

But the steps wouldn't change. They change only when next screen is displayed.

Comment: Consider adding a screenshot of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Up to install4j 7.0.3, wizard steps can only change when the screen changes.

Thanks to your feedback, it will be possible in install4j 7.0.4 to call  `WizardContext#setWizardIndexKey` and `WizardContext#setWizardIndex` in actions or form component event handlers with the intended effect.

Comment: Is there a way i can refresh/redraw the display  progress using API?  is yes, i can chane display progress screen step using the apis above and then trigger refresh/redraw

Comment: There is currently no workaround, please see the edit to my answer. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented, so you can try it out.

Comment: Thank you. And when is the 7.0.4 is planed to be released?

Comment: Later this month